# xlsxwriter chart with multiple categories

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

My excel chart has two index columns: 'Month' and 'Year'.
How can I combine them in the python code below to achieve a graph that looks like the one below? To be specific, how do I specify the multiple categories?

```
chart.add_series({
    'categories': .............,
    'values': ['Sheet 1', 0, 1, 10, 1]
})
```

Excel graph I want to achieve

[image]

I already tried:

```
chart.add_series({
    'categories': [['Sheet1', 0, 0, 10, 0], ['Sheet1', 0, 1, 10, 1]]
    'values': ['Sheet1', 0, 2, 10, 2]
})
```

Comment: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_combined.html this seems to be dealing with your problem

Answer (score 2):

XlsxWriter supports clustered charts like this. See this [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_clustered.html) from the docs.

[image]

The main trick to get this to work is to specify the categories as 2D ranges (from column A to column B). This creates the clusters.